# PostgreSQL to_char ignores locale

Tags: postgresql, date, locale, to-char

I have PgSQL 9.6 on Fedora 29. System and PgSQL is running with cs_CZ.UTF-8 locale. But when I use to_char(date, 'Day Dy') I get english day name.

```
#shell> echo $LANG
cs_CZ.utf8

#sql> show lc_time;
cs_CZ.UTF-8
#sql> select to_char(now()::date, 'Day Dy');
Monday    Mon
#sql> set lc_time to 'it_IT.utf8';
#sql> show lc_time;
it_IT.utf8
#sql> select to_char(now()::date, 'Day Dy');
Monday    Mon
```

Is there anything I can set to make it working?

Comment: YOU’ve answered the question, but I might add that you don’t need `::date` in your sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have missed the 'TM' modifier, so the correct format is

```
#sql> select to_char(now()::date, 'TMDay TMDy');
Pondělí Po
```